# Detecting Built-in Barcode Scanner

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am creating an app on Android/Xamarin that performs barcode scans. While I have already achieved this I would also like the app to determine if the phone has a built-in barcode scanner and as such use this.

I have found an answer on here that says that I could look at the manufacturer or model of the phone and work from there as this quite a unique feature of the phone. But these handsets are not universal across the industry. Making this an impractical solution.

Does anyone know anyway that this can be done?

Or even return a full list of hardware on the device that can be worked with?
I was thinking about using `ManagementObjectSearcher` but I'm not sure how this works with mobile applications, just straight C#.

Even finding someway to interact with the hardware so as to pick out the scanner.

I have searched high and low with very little information and answers available.

Comment: From the various Android tablets and phones that have Barcode readers built-in that I have seen, they all have their own SDKs that have to be used to access the hardware as there is no "standard" way within AOSP , each manufacture integrates custom hardware and normally writes a native device driver that is then bound by a Java library. Once you have access to the device and their SDK, creating an Xamarin.Android Binding library is the way to go.

Comment: Yes that could be a solution. I was hoping that it wouldnt come to that, but if needs must.